# REST API - MALFORMED_REQUEST issue

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk

Im having issues with the REST API. Its returning MALFORMED_REQUEST: “Incoming JSON request does not map to API request” and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Have been through the code over and over, and cant seem to see what the problem is. I've output the contents of getData in the exception, but its not giving me any idea as to where the issue might be. I'm sure its going to be something simple, but I cant find it.

I've output the contents of getData in the exception, but its not giving me any idea as to where the issue might be, other than the error itself

```
object(PayPal\Api\Item)#8 (1) { ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(29) "5155 Tranport Request Deposit" ["currency"]=> string(3) "EUR" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["sku"]=> string(4) "5155" ["price"]=> string(2) "10" } } object(PayPal\Api\ItemList)#9 (1) { ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(1) { ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(PayPal\Api\Item)#8 (1) { ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(29) "5155 Tranport Request Deposit" ["currency"]=> string(3) "EUR" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["sku"]=> string(4) "5155" ["price"]=> string(2) "10" } } } } } object(stdClass)#15 (4) { ["name"]=> string(17) "MALFORMED_REQUEST" ["message"]=> string(49) "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request" ["information_link"]=> string(74) "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST" ["debug_id"]=> string(13) "7bd31dedb98ef" }
```

```
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
require 'ppbootstrap.php';
if (empty($_POST['item_number'])) {
    throw new Exception('This script should not be called directly, expected post data');
}

$currency = 'EUR';
$amountPayable = 10.00;
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
$desc = $_POST['item_number'].' Tranport Request Deposit';
$inv = $_POST['item_number'];

//Create the item
$item = new Item();
$item->setName($desc)
    ->setCurrency($currency)
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setSku($inv)
    ->setPrice($amountPayable);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item));
var_dump($item);
var_dump($itemList);


$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency($currency)
    ->setTotal($amountPayable);


$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amountPayable)
    ->setItemList($itemList)
    ->setDescription($desc)
    ->setInvoiceNumber($inv);


$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($paypalConfig['return_url'])
    ->setCancelUrl($paypalConfig['cancel_url']);


$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

$request = clone $payment;

try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e) {


var_dump(json_decode($e->getData()));
//throw new Exception($e);
//echo $e->getCode(); 
//echo '<br /><br />';
//echo $e->getData();
//echo '<br /><br />';
//var_dump($request);
die($e);
}
header('location:' . $payment->getApprovalLink());
exit(1);
```

Bootstrap file

```
<?php
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

require './vendor/autoload.php';
// For test payments we want to enable the sandbox mode. If you want to put live
// payments through then this setting needs changing to `false`.
$enableSandbox = true;
// PayPal settings. Change these to your account details and the relevant URLs
// for your site.
$paypalConfig = [
    'client_id' => 'hidden',
    'client_secret' => 'hidden',
    'return_url' => 'http://hidden/success.html',
    'cancel_url' => 'http://hidden/cancelled.html'
];

$apiContext = getApiContext($paypalConfig['client_id'], $paypalConfig['client_secret'], $enableSandbox);

function getApiContext($clientId, $clientSecret, $enableSandbox = false)
{
    $apiContext = new ApiContext(
        new OAuthTokenCredential($clientId, $clientSecret)
    );
    $apiContext->setConfig([
        'mode' => $enableSandbox ? 'sandbox' : 'live'
    ]);
    return $apiContext;
}
```

Comment: You will need to show us the data you are sending please.

Comment: They are all in variables at the top, other than the $inv which at present is 5155. Not sure what else you need there, but if there is something, please let me know and I can send over

Comment: ```
$currency = 'EUR';
$amountPayable = 10.00;
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
$desc = $_POST['item_number'].' Tranport Request Deposit';
$inv = $_POST['item_number'];
```

Comment: What's in the $apiContext variable? It doesn't seem to be declared before

Comment: Ah, thats from my bootstrap file. Have added the content of this above.

Comment: Found it, finally. Been looking at it for that long I wasnt seeing the obvious. Its here

```

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency($currency)
    ->setTotal($amountPayable);
```

I should be passing in the $amount object, not my value which is $amountPayable

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant the raw JSON being sent. You beat me to it.